# Infopath and Sections

Tags: 2010, infopath

I'm trying to work with InfoPath and create multiple optional sections but every time I insert a new section it always groups ALL objects under SharePointListItem_RW in the group.

So if I have this group hidden, it automatically hides ALL OTHER groups and disables any fields not in the group.

How do I have multiple optional sections in a single form?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a section to a field. It sounds like you are working with a SharePoint List form. So, in the Fields task pane, set the fields to show in advanced view (should be a link toward the bottom of the Fields task pane).

Then, right click a field - any field - and select "More" in the control options - from there you can choose a section.
[image: Control Options]

Alternatively, add a section to your form that is bound to the main SharePointListItem_RW group and change the binding.

You can have as many sections on the form as you like all bound to the same field or group, by the way. I don't know that you'll truly be able to make them "optional" - if you have the user remove the section, it will remove the field it is bound to - but you can add conditional formatting to show hide them.